# why do I have two different results if I run a program through terminal(as root) or /etc/init.d(or /etc/rc.local)

Tags: debian, root, init-script, privileges

**Background:**

I use Debian Lenny on an embedded device

```
uname -a
Linux device 3.4.0 #83 Sun May 26 17:07:14 CEST 2013 armv4l GNU/Linux
```

I have a C code (say `my_C_program`) that calls a board specific binary file (via `system("spictl someparameters")` ) called `spictl` to use SPI interface

```
user:~# ls -al /usr/local/bin/spictl
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root staff      24 Jun  9  2011 spiflashctl -> /initrd/sbin/spiflashctl
```

if I run my code (`my_C_program`) from the command line

```
user:~# /user/sbin/my_C_program
```

the `spictl` is executed without problem and outputs data from the SPI interface.

**Problem:**

I need the program to be run when the board is powered. Therefore, I add `/user/sbin/my_C_program` line before the `exit 0` at`/etc/rc.local`. When the board is powered, the my_C_program is executed and `spictl` is executed but the SPI interface does not output any data.

I tried to run the program via `/etc/init.d/` script on [this link](http://werxltd.com/wp/2012/01/05/simple-init-d-script-template/). The script works fine and it executes the `my_C_program`, the program executes the `spictl` successfully (as `system()` return value says), but the SPI interface does not output any data!

```
ls -l /usr/sbin/my_C_program
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 61713 Jun 28  2013 /usr/sbin/my_C_program
```

`top` shows that the program is run as root

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                          
 1095 root      20   0  2524 1140  924 R  4.2  1.8   0:00.35 top                                                                              
 1033 root      RT   0 35092  34m 1852 S  3.0 56.5   0:14.06 node
```

**Question**

if I execute the `my_C_program` on terminal, the program calls the `spictl` (via `system(spictl someparameters)`) and it is executed without any problem. But if I run `my_C_program` through `/etc/rc.local` or `/etc/init.d` script, then `spictl` does not work as it supposed to be. I suspect that it has something to do with the root privilege. When I execute the program on the terminal (as root) all works fine. But I guess `/etc/rc.local` and `/etc/init.d` somehow runs the program with a lower privilege. I could not really solve the difference between executing a command from the terminal as root or executing the program via `/etc/rc.local` or `/etc/init.d/` script. If you also think that it is a privilege problem, could you please explain how can I ensure that init.d script or rc.local would run the program with the highest privilege. Or what could be the issue?

Please note that the problem/question is not SPI related.

P.S. in order not to have unnecessary conversation like "oh Debian lenny is too old, you should use wheezy etc.", the board has armv4l processor and as the producer says it does not support wheezy because of some processor instructions.

Comment: It's probably a path issue. Try to use the full path to the spictl binary.

Comment: Marco, it makes a lot sense! thank you I am going to try it now

Comment: +1 I actually like the P.S. especially since you're talking about init stuff that hasn't changed in about 30 years.

Comment: the problem is solved, as Marco pointed out, it was a path problem. thanks a lot for the help. and it is good to know alternative possibilities as msw points out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're C executable probably requires some environment variables to be set to function. For example the env. variable `$PATH` or `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. There also other variables such as `$HOME` which won't be set until a user has logged in.

This last one might be necessary for your app to access config files and/or log files, for example.

Answer (score 1):

To investigate what's going on, redirect the output of your program (especially the errors) to a file.

```
/usr/sbin/my_C_program >/root/my_C_program.out 2.>&1
```

If that doesn't give any clue, break out the artillery: install [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace).

```
strace /usr/sbin/my_C_program -o /root/my_C_program.from_etc_local.strace
```

Also run the program from the command line and compare the traces. Even if you don't understand what most of the lines are doing, the first few lines where the traces differ should give a clue. Ignore most differences that only concern integer values as these are typically due to different load addresses and focus on where the system calls differ.

Most likely, the program is looking for some file which is fails to find because it is invoked from a different directory, or because `PATH` or some other environment variable isn't set to the value that you expect when you start the program from `/etc/rc.local`.